# How to keep a trailing empty array element?

Tags: bash

When I read an array this way:

```
IFS=, read -r -a a <<<',,,'
```

And output the array this way:

```
(IFS=, ; echo "${a[*]}")
```

I lose one comma.

The `read` reads just three elements.

```
$ echo ${#a[@]}
3
```

How can I tell `read` to treat 3 delimiters as 4 empty elements?

Comment: Add a character on the end of the input and remove it after read from the last array element.

Comment: @KamilCuk I could not have imagined, that Bash's read works better with DOS files as with Unix files.